# Table inside table ng-repeat not displayed correctly?

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a 2 Lines X 3 Columnus table in which, in the second row, I am adding a table in every cell. In these tables, I am using Angular with ng-repeat to display data. My problem is that the data is not diplayed correctly. Here is my code and a screenshot of the result.

```
<tr>
    <td style="font-weight: bold">
        Europe 
    </td>
    <td style="font-weight: bold">
        Europe 
    </td>
    <td style="font-weight: bold">
        Europe 
    </td>
    <td>...</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td style="font-weight: bold">
        <table id="table3" class="table table-striped">
            <tr>
                <th>CustomerID</th>
                <th>CustomerUserID</th>
                <th>Environment</th>
                <th>Time Elapsed</th>
                <th>Migrated </th>

                <tr ng-repeat="runEu in runMig24InEurope | filter:searchRunEur">
                    <td>{{ runEu.customerID }}</td>
                    <td>{{ runEu.customerUserID}}</td>
                    <td>{{ runEu.environment}}</td>
                </tr>
        </table>
    </td>

    <td style="font-weight: bold">
        <table id="table4" class="table table-striped">
            <tr>
                <th>CustomerID</th>
                <th>CustomerUserID</th>
                <th>Environment</th>

                <tr ng-repeat="succEu in succMig24InEurope | filter:searchSuccEur">
                    <td>{{ succEu.customerID }}</td>
                    <td>{{ succEu.customerUserID}}</td>
                    <td>{{ succEu.environment}}</td>
                </tr>
        </table>
    </td>

    <td style="font-weight: bold">
        <table id="table5" class="table table-striped">
            <tr>
                <th>CustomerID</th>
                <th>CustomerUserID</th>
                <th>Environment</th>

                <tr ng-repeat="errEu in onErrMig24InEurope | filter:searchErrEur">
                    <td>{{ errEu.customerID }}</td>
                    <td>{{ errEu.customerUserID}}</td>
                    <td>{{ errEu.environment}}</td>
                </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
    <td>...</td>
</tr>
```

[See what is displayed here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YgtBC.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the Table inside the `<td>` tag was displayed in the center of the cell. To resolve that, I had to put `<td valign="top">`.

Answer (score 1):

You're not properly closing your tags:

```
<table id="table3" class="table table-striped">
    **<tr>**
        <th>CustomerID</th>
        <th>CustomerUserID</th>
        <th>Environment</th>
        <th>Time Elapsed</th>
        <th>Migrated </th>

        <tr ng-repeat="runEu in runMig24InEurope | filter:searchRunEur">
            <td>{{ runEu.customerID }}</td>
            <td>{{ runEu.customerUserID}}</td>
            <td>{{ runEu.environment}}</td>
        </tr>
    **</tr>**
</table>
```

The `<tr>` isn't closed (in all your tables)

Comment: Still having the same problem. I think  it's related to Angular.

Comment: Sorry @MartijnWelker could not post my code in a comment. How could I do so?

Comment: Do you think it's an Angular related problem?

Comment: @RafaAyadi no, your whole html structure is just strange, why did you decide to go for this strange form of a table layout ?

Comment: I wanted to put 3 aligned tables side by side, so I opted for putting 3 tables, each in a column of a global table. I thought that was the most proper way.

Comment: The reason I am saying that I think it's an angular problem is that the small tables are displayed exactly in the center. For example if I have an 8 row table and a 2 row table, the two row table will be displayed aligned with the 4th and 5th row of the big table. Here is a screenshot. http://i.imgur.com/ch2UKHQ.png

Comment: @RafaAyadi And how exactly do you think angular would cause this ? This looks more like a html problem.

Comment: I don't know, but when I added a filter here is the result : 1- When no filter is applied, we can notice that the two tables headers are aligned. http://i.imgur.com/XahC6nn.png  2- When I apply a filter, the header of the second table goes aligned exactly with the central row of the 1st table. http://i.imgur.com/MGRwEiT.png  . Please let me know if you have anby ideas. Thanks!